# Tableau: Average sales for weekdays

Tags: average, tableau-api, linechart

I'm fairly new to Tableau and got stuck at a problem for a while now.

In my dataset are salesdata down to the day of payment.
Basically it looks like this:

Date:        Revenue:
2015-01-01   45,45
2015-01-02   20,05
2015-01-03   05,55
2015-01-04   57,33
...          ...

What I am trying to establish is a line chart that shows a week from Monday to Sunday (column) and tells me how much revenue there was on an average Monday, Tuesday, and so on. It would take into account the 52 Mondays of 2015 and display the average revenue for Mondays.

Every suggestion is much appreciated!
Cheers, Markus

Answer (score 0):

Create a calc field on your Date for weekday:

```
datename('weekday',[Date])
```

Place this on the Columns shelf. Place Revenue on the Rows shelf and change the aggregation to AVG.

You can change the Start of week to default to Mondays by the following:

[image: change date properties]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, Bernando.

I've tried this already but the numbers do not seem to match. The total amount of revenues generated on a Monday is 67.677 and the average value is calculated to be 120,94. I was expecting something like 67.677/52 weeks = 1.301,48. Any chance to get it like this?